# Add application manifest to a win32 application in eclipse

Tags: c++, manifest, eclipse-cdt, mingw32

How do I add an application manifest to a Win32 application being developed in Eclipse ?
I want to add a manifest in order to use  version 6 of `Comctl32.dll` which, according to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289524%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) article is necessary to create form controls with a Windows XP visual style.
I'm using MingW32 toolchain with eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question:
Add `CREATEPROCESS_MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID RT_MANIFEST "YourApp.exe.manifest"` to the `.rc` file before you compile it with MinGW resource compiler, `windres`