# How to embed manifest file to exe in eclipse?

Tags: c++, eclipse, exe, manifest, eclipse-cdt

I have created exe for my project in eclipse(kepler version) through 'build project' option, but when i tries to run the exe on some other machine it is showing UAC pop-up and asking for administrative privileges, for that issue i have written manifest file of name EXEname.exe.manifest and saved it in same directory where source files gets stored.

But I am not able to link manifest file to the exe while building project, is there any project settings require before building project or there is another way of embedding manifest file ??

Comment: How to link manifest file in eclipse is not answered there.

Comment: what compiler are you using? From what location are you trying to run it ?

Comment: I am using MinGW compiler and running final exe using command line option.

Comment: Did you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7245962/add-application-manifest-to-a-win32-application-in-eclipse ?

Comment: I have seen that post but still not able to do run exe on another machine..can you tell me what project settings need to be done if i added resource file as given in that post ??